# How to tell if a product is published or not?

Tags: shopify

I'd like to use the `published` field on products that's documented here in the [Shopify API](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#update):

> Hide a published product by changing the published attribute to false

I can change the flag on any product, but I have not figured out yet how to get the `published` field back from the API. It's not listed the [list of fields of the `Product`
object](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#show).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `published_at` field of individual products directly as described [here](http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_api_gem_with_the_credentials_of_a_private_application#Hide_.E2.80.94_or_publish_.E2.80.94_a_bunch_of_products):

```
product.published_at = nil; product.save              # hides product
product.published_at = Time.now.utc; product.save     # makes product visible
```

You can also hide a collection of products by setting `published` to false as described [here](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/t/api-product-collection-hide-publish-28916#comment-28919):

```
collection = ShopifyAPI::CustomCollection.find(params[:collection_id])
collection.published = false
collection.save
```

**UPDATED**

Now that I understand the question better, here is the answer you want. You can't really get the 'published' value back as there isn't really a `published` attribute on a product.  You can, however, check the `published_at` field and check if it's `nil` (not published).  Setting `published = false` apparently sets this to nil for you.

Comment: Thank you, but I am interested in how I can GET the `published` field for an individual product, not set it!

Comment: You can't get it back - there isn't such an attribute.  The API is likley setting `published_at = nil` behind the scenes.  What you can do is check the `published_at` attribute to see if it's nil (not published).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up and sorry that I didn't quite get it the first time you explained. ;)

Comment: Same here :)  Updated to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a published status very easily. It is in the API as an endpoint: published_status
This returns published, unpublished and any.
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product
Usage:

```
To get an array of all published products:
GET /admin/products.json?publish_status=published

To get an array of all unpublished products:
GET /admin/products.json?publish_status=unpublished
```

Then iterate the array and find the product you want. Some sample php that does this:

```
function isPublished($shopify, $myprodid) {
  $products = $shopify('GET /admin/products.json?publish_status=unpublished');
  foreach($products as $prod) {
    if($prod['id'] == $myprodid)
      return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

Iterating the unpublished should be quick unless you have a large amount of unpublished products. Then swap the test.